# Gravar histório/cache do WebView

Tags: cache, webview, android-webview

Estou montando um aplicativo `WebView`, onde a primeira tela é de *login*. Gostaria que os campos *login* e senha pudessem ser gravados, assim quando o usuário fechar o *app* esses dados não fossem perdidos.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução, se tratando de `WebView`, é você salvar os dados do formulário usando o método `setSaveFormData()` usando a classe pública [**WebSettings**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html). Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.loadUrl("https://jonsnow.com/login");
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
```